# How to align single widgets in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, alignment, text-align

I want to align a Flutter widget within its parent. I know that I can center a widget by wrapping it in a Center widget.

```
  Center(
    child: Text("widget"),
  )
```

But how do I align it to the right, bottom, top middle, etc?

**Notes:**

I am talking about a single child, not multiple children in a Row or Column. See these SO questions:

- [Align Text widgets in a row widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50588508/align-text-widgets-on-a-in-a-row-widget)
- [FLUTTER | Right Align not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50640161/flutter-right-align-not-working)

This one is on the right track but I am trying to make a more cannonical question:

- [How to left align the OutlineButton icon in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52637354/how-to-left-align-the-outlinebutton-icon-in-flutter)

Answer (score 226, accepted):

## How to align widgets

To align a child widget within its parent you use the [`Align`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/Align-class.html) widget. If you know how to use the `Center` widget then you are the right track because `Center` is just a special case of `Align`.

Wrap the widget you wish to align with the Align widget and set its alignment property. For example, this would align a text widget to the middle right of the parent.

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
  child: Text("widget"),
)
```

Other options are

- `Alignment.topLeft`
- `Alignment.topCenter`
- `Alignment.topRight`
- `Alignment.centerLeft`
- `Alignment.center`
- `Alignment.centerRight`
- `Alignment.bottomLeft`
- `Alignment.bottomCenter`
- `Alignment.bottomRight`

Here is what that looks like:

[image]

You are not limited to these locations. You can align your widget anywhere. by specifying an x,y pair, where `(0,0)` is the center of the view and the edges are `1.0` unit around it. Maybe an image would help:

[image: alignment]

where for any relative position `(x,y)`

- `Alignment.topLeft` is `Alignment(-1.0, -1.0)`
- `Alignment.topCenter` is `Alignment(0.0, -1.0)`
- `Alignment.topRight` is `Alignment(1.0, -1.0)`
- `Alignment.centerLeft` is `Alignment(-1.0, 0.0)`
- `Alignment.center` is `Alignment(0.0, 0.0)`
- `Alignment.centerRight` is `Alignment(1.0, 0.0)`
- `Alignment.bottomLeft` is `Alignment(-1.0, 1.0)`
- `Alignment.bottomCenter` is `Alignment(0.0, 1.0)`
- `Alignment.bottomRight` is `Alignment(1.0, 1.0)`

Notice in the image that the alignment `(x,y)` doesn't need to be within the range `[-1, +1]`. The alignment `(1,2)` means it is at the right side of the widget and below the widget half again as much as its height.

Here is an example of a custom alignment position.

```
Align(
  alignment: Alignment(0.7, -0.5),
  child: Text("widget"),
)
```

[image: alignment]

### Supplemental code

Here is the `main.dart` code used to make the above examples for your cut-and-paste convenience.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: myLayoutWidget(),
      ),
    );
  }
}

Widget myLayoutWidget() {
  return Align(
    alignment: Alignment(0.7, -0.5),
    child: Text(
      "widget",
      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
    ),
  );
}
```

Comment: What about alignment to start of screen to support rtl and ltr.

Comment: @EslamSamehAhmed, Good question. I'm not sure about that. Maybe you could get the directionality from the context and set the location accordingly.

Answer (score 28):

```
  Expanded(
    child: Align(
      alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
      child: Text("widget"),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet. What does the Expanded widget do here?

Comment: `Expanded` will fill up all available space (and make any sibling widgets take up less space). It will place the child in the center of the newly created space, and you will need to use `Align` if you don't want it in the center (of the expanded space)

Comment: This only works if your parent is either a `Column` or `Row`.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad SizedBox.expand() can be used without Column or Row (flex) as parent.

Answer (score 2):

## Flutter  Align Widget also Flutter Animated Align

You can easily align any widget in flutter using the flutter Align widget.

```
Align(
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(
        "ALIGN WIDGET",
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      )),
```

also, you can animate it:

```
AnimatedAlign(
        alignment: clicked ? Alignment.bottomCenter : Alignment.topCenter,
        duration: const Duration(seconds: 2),
        child: const Text(
          "ANIMATED WIDGET",
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 35, fontWeight: FontWeight.w800),
        )),
```