# Flutter: How to align widget to the topRight of column?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to align my more options button to the top right corner in in my column, according to the this SO answer.

[How to align single widgets in Flutter?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53716572/9779791)

Here's my code.

```
return Card(
      color: Colors.blueAccent,
      child: Container(
        height: 100,
        width: 350,
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(
              'Day ${widget._dayNumber}',
              style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
              ),
            ),
            Align(alignment: Alignment.topRight,
             child: IconButton(onPressed: () {}, icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),)),

          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

[image: Text first, then align]

And if I change the order of align and text, this happens.

[image: align first, then text]

I want to display my button on the top right corner while keeping Text widget on the center top, but align widget seems to take whole line(row).

Is there a way to do correctly achieve that, or do I need to wrap them both in a row?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've used Stack and Positioned widget to achieve that effect.

[image: Final]

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: <Widget>[
        Card(
          color: Colors.blueAccent,
          child: Container(
            height: 100,
            width: 350,
            child: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                Text(
                  'Day ${widget._dayNumber}',
                  style: TextStyle(
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Positioned(
          top: 0,
          right: 0,
          child: IconButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Another option for a widget instead of Positioned with two properties set to `0` is to use an `Align` and set the `alignment` property to `topRight`

Answer (score 6):

You need to wrap with `Row` if you want to make them in the same `Column`
[image]

```
  return Card(
    color: Colors.blueAccent,
    child: Container(
      height: 100,
      width: 350,
      child: Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(),
              Text(
                'Day 1',
                style: TextStyle(
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
              ),
              IconButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                icon: Icon(Icons.more_vert),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
```